# condition in celltemplate uigrid

Tags: angularjs

i want to change color in cell ui grid. please help.
this is my image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGHR0.png)

Comment: can you also post the cell template? or the setup of the grid? or however you have it set up

Comment: this is my ui grid. http://jsfiddle.net/yLcv8mw7/

Answer (score 0):

You have this cell template for the ID:

```
{
    field: 'BookingId',
    displayName: 'ID',
    cellTemplate: function () {
        return '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color:lightblue;" ng-if="row.entity.BookingId == \'19\'">{{row.entity.BookingId}}</div><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color:LightCoral;" ng-if="row.entity.BookingId == \'18\'">{{row.entity.BookingId}}</div>';
    }
}
```

It could instead be something like this:

```
{
    field: 'BookingId',
    displayName: 'ID',
    cellTemplate: function () {
        let color = 'white';
        if (row.entity.BookingId.indexOf('C') !== -1) { color = 'lightblue'; }
        else if (row.entity.BookingId.indexOf('V') !== -1) { color = 'lightred'; }
        else if (row.entity.BookingId.indexOf('P') !== -1) { color = 'lightgreen'; }

        return '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color:' + color + ';" ng-if="row.entity.BookingId == \'19\'">{{row.entity.BookingId}}</div><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color:LightCoral;" ng-if="row.entity.BookingId == \'18\'">{{row.entity.BookingId}}</div>';
    }
},
```